# Vuejs :progressbar on data fetching before navigating to route

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have implemented data fetching before navigating to the route ie the route didn't loaded until the data loaded from API.

Everything works fine but i want to add progress bar on route loading but the doc didn't say the implementation.

Here is my code

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {


data () {
    return {
      post: null,
      error: null
    }
  },

 beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then((response,error)=>{
      next(vm => vm.setData(response, error))
    })
  },

   beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    this.post = null
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1fh').then((response,error)=>{
      this.setData(response,error)
      next()
    })
  },

  methods: {

    setData (response,error) {

           if (error) {
                console.log("Error",error);
            this.error = err.toString()
           } else {
            this.post = response.data
           }     
    }
 }


}
```

**Component**

```
<div class="post">
     <h2>Sample child</h2>

    <div v-if="error" class="error">
      {{ error }}
    </div>

    <div v-if="post" class="content">
      <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This will load when i click on the route `me/posts`

Official doc
https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

Answer (score 0):

i will share the approach i followed to implement a logic that requires loading icon to be shown whilst waiting for AJAX response. Component lifecycle hook `created()` will be used to implement this feature

The approach used for displaying the loading icon could also be replaced to a progress bar with few modifications.

You can take a look at my vuejs project in github which will help to understand what i tried to describe here 
 https://github.com/divine3/vuejs/tree/master/basic

**How did i implement this logic**

- Create a Loading.vue component.
- Setup an eventBus.
- Communication from any other components to Loading.vue will happen only via eventBus
- Emit event an event using the eventBus from `created()` hook. This event emission will happen when the component mapped to the route is invoked (i.e) when route gets changed.
- Create a Listener on Loading.vue component
- Once event is emitted during route change, the Listener on Loading.vue component will receive the event and loading icon will be displayed.
- In this demo project (in my github) the Loading.vue component by itself will have the control to remove the loading icon.
- To remove the loader automatically, a new event has to be emitted via eventBus and a listener has to be created in Loading.vue. This particular flow is not added in this demo project

Using `beforeRouteEnter` for implementing this same logic doesnot work if we bookmark `http://localhost:8081/#/planet` and trigger it via browser because of the order in which the components are created.